# Using ::after and ::before to go outside padding bounds

Tags: html, css, layout, padding

[image: Text inside a blue box with a dashed line background, smaller red box behind and slightly offset]

```css
p {
  background: rgba(80,150,220,1);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align:center;
}
p::before {
  content="asdf";
  background: rgba(220,150,80,1);
  width = 50px;
  height = 50px;
  top = - 25px;
  left = - 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>TEXT HERE</p>
</body>
```

**Without altering HTML**

This is my attempt. Let me know if you have any better solution.

Dotted line is supposed to be shown it just represents the element size.

I am trying to keep my padding and margin to 0.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to accomplish here. Could you please explain the issue in more detail?

Comment: I think the declaration for `p::before` is not right, the property and value should be separated with this `:` not `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify padding and margin but make them 0 visually by considering the same amount of padding as negative margin then relies on some background coloration:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
  padding: 20px 0 0  20px;
  background: 
    /* Top red line (width:80% height:20px) */
    linear-gradient(red,red) 0 0/80% 20px,
    /* left red line (width:20px height:80%)*/
    linear-gradient(red,red) 0 0/20px 80%,
    /* Main background; color only the content area (not the padding)*/
    rgba(80,150,220,1) content-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
  text-align:center;
}
body {
 padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">TEXT HERE</div>
```

And if you want with pseudo element:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(80, 150, 220, 1);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border-top: 20px solid red;
  border-left: 20px solid red;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">TEXT HERE</div>
```

Comment: Based on the code provided, I think the OP might benefit from a bit more context. The CSS alone is pretty self-explanatory to us but probably not to everyone.